# Automatically add/remove entry to/from /etc/hosts when enabling/disabling apache2 virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, debian-wheezy, perl

When I create virtualhosts, I almost always forget to add an entry to `/etc/hosts` until I've attempted to check the site in a web browser and moaned about the oversight. What I want to do is modify `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` so that, when run, the following happens:

1. `a2ensite` looks for the site entry in `/etc/hosts`. If it's not found, append the site to 127.0.0.1 entries. Otherwise, do nothing.
2. `a2dissite` looks for the site entry in `/etc/hosts`. If it's found, remove the site from 127.0.0.1. Otherwise, do nothing.

Either that (which MAMP does on OS X) or add a reminder that I need to edit `etc/hosts` to get the virtualhost working.

I attempted to edit these files, but, seeing as I don't know PERL, I'm not sure what modifications to make. Also, I'm not sure that editing those files is the best option, in the event that apt overwrites my changes when upgrading apache2.

Comment: Why do you need the entry in `/etc/hosts` - are you using name resolution to target a listener address (eg `<VirtualHost example.com:80>`)?

Comment: If I don't add an entry to `/etc/hosts`,  I get an 'Unable to connect to server; {browser} is unable to find the site at {xyz.loc}' message in any browser I use to interact with the site.